# How can I insert a record retrieved from an ms access table into an sql server table?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access, ssms

I have an MS Access database table that I exported to SQL Server 2012 without the data.  So now I'd like to copy the data from the access table to the sql table line by line.

```
    Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ACCESS_DB_DataConnectionString").ToString())
    Dim comm As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * FROM " + accessTable)
    Dim rdr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        rdr = comm.ExecuteReader

        While rdr.Read
             InsertRecord()
        End While
        rdr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error
    Finally
        comm.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub InsertRecord()
    'What do I do here?  Select into?  But how?
End Sub
```

I don't want to use a regular insert because I don't care to type out all of the column names.  The end goal is to copy what records I can and skip over and obtain the IDs of all the rows that error out.

Thank you

Comment: The biggest issue you will have when working with databases is forcing yourself to think about data movements as `line by line`.

Comment: What is so hard about getting the column names?   And you can have Linked Server to Access from SSMS.

Comment: To be honest, its a terrible set of tables (not just one) with a gazillion columns.  I don't want to do it for every table.

Comment: Really a gazillion columns and you tried import with failures and you think the question as stated is the solution?  -1

Comment: eh.  its ok if you don't know.  Adam gave a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the "SQL Server Import and Export Data" program that comes with SQL Server Management Studio.  It does a spectacular job of transferring data to/from SQL Server and a variety of other formats like Access, Excel, OLE, and many others.

[image: SQL Server Import and Export Data]

Comment: Originally, I did use the import/export data program from SQLServer; however, it would error out part way through the data copy with different errors and give no detail as to where.  Most of the time.  Sometimes I was able to track down null values where they were not supposed to be but for the most part, I was getting barely a 1/3 of the data before getting shut down.  I even tried using the ignore on error option, but it never ignored them.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I actually kept running it after it error'd out and found that each time it got further.  I appreciate the help.